# not displaying all child categories

Tags: arrays, wordpress, foreach

I've got a basic script grabbing all posts of children cats of a given category, I am then shuffling the resulting posts and displaying them. So I have added a new child category of cat 4, but I am not getting any of the new posts in that sub cat to show up using my current script. I have tried changing child of and specifically grabbing these by the cat_ID and they show up. As well as just reloading many many times to see if they ever load in but are not in the 30 I am pulling due to the small number of posts in comparison to the posts in other sub cats.

My code is as follows

```
<?php
        $posts = array();
         $categories = get_categories( 'child_of=4' );
         foreach($categories as $category) {
           $args=array(
            'showposts' => 30,
            'category__in' => array($category->term_id)
           );
         $posts = $posts + get_posts($args);
        } // Close your foreach here
             shuffle($posts);
              if ($posts) {
                foreach($posts as $post) {
                  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <div <?php post_class('boxy');?>><div class="soc-label" ></div>

                  <?php 
                      if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                      $full_image_url =  wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
                      echo '<a href="' . $full_image_url[0] . '" rel="lightbox" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
                      the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                      echo '</a>';
                    }
                   ?>

                <?php the_content(''); ?>
                </div>

        <?php } 
           } 

        ?>
```

Thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

get_posts has an "posts_per_page" argument for posts limiting.
you use "showposts" that is for WP_Query

Comment: When I change to "posts_per_page" I get results from only 1 sub category.. so I've got to have more than that wrong..